# Date selection and date format in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework, date-format

i have to make a select transaction with a microsoft SQL db. I have to select the entry in a given range of time. So i've made my little form with the datepicker of jquery. The datetime field in the database has this output:

```
 Jan 1 2014 12:00:00:000AM
```

This is the format of the jquery datepicker:

```
 {dateFormat: 'M dd yy'}
```

WHen i receive the GET call (but i've tested even with a POST and the output is the same)from the form i add the hours to the date (I'm using Zend framework 1.12):

```
    $startdate= $this->getRequest()->getParam('datepicker');
    $startdate= $startdate." 12:00:00:000AM";
    $enddate= $this->getRequest()->getParam('datepicker1');
    $enddate= $enddate." 12:00:00:000AM";
```

But it probably is not the right one as my select query:

```
 SELECT [Document No_]
       ,[Sell-to Customer No_]
       ,[Planned Delivery Date]
       ,[Description]
       ,[Description 2]
 FROM dbo.SyncroPlanningTable 
 WHERE CAST([Planned Delivery Date] as datetime)>='".$startdate."' 
  AND CAST([Planned Delivery Date] as datetime)<='".$enddate."' 
 ORDER BY [Planned Delivery Date] ASC
```

doesn't give any output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be the output of the SQL datetime column, but it's actually stored as

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]

Thus the passed format needs to resemble

> 2014-01-01 12:00:00:000AM

[Relevant MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)